# mysqlreport showing extreme Com_admin_comma

Tags: mysql

My Questions section of mysqlreport shows the following result:

```
__ Questions ___________________________________________________________
Total           9.04M     1.6/s
  Com_          9.39M     1.7/s  %Total: 103.87
  -Unknown      9.05M     1.7/s          100.13
  QC Hits       6.50M     1.2/s           71.90
  DMS           2.02M     0.4/s           22.31
  COM_QUIT    185.75k     0.0/s            2.05
Slow 10 s           3     0.0/s            0.00  %DMS:   0.00  Log: OFF
DMS             2.02M     0.4/s           22.31
  SELECT        1.40M     0.3/s           15.53         69.59
  UPDATE      591.79k     0.1/s            6.54         29.33
  INSERT       21.57k     0.0/s            0.24          1.07
  DELETE           51     0.0/s            0.00          0.00
  REPLACE           0       0/s            0.00          0.00
Com_            9.39M     1.7/s          103.87
  admin_comma   9.12M     1.7/s          100.82
  set_option  267.32k     0.0/s            2.96
  change_db     2.72k     0.0/s            0.03
```

Googling com_admin_comma does not give me any idea, nor does the MySQL internal docs. Does anyone have a clue about this?

The server runs a custom CMS which connects to two databases simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Com_admin_comma` is actually truncated and should be `Com_admin_commands`.  It's a counter that tracks a subset of the commands that you can run on a MySQL server.

[There's a list here of what it tracks in the first reply](http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/69813-show-status-confusion).

The important bit from that page:

Com_admin_commands includes:

```
COM_TABLE_DUMP
COM_CHANGE_USER
COM_BINLOG_DUMP
COM_SHUTDOWN
COM_PING
COM_DEBUG
```

Comment: The documentation of mysqlreport explains I can split them by using --com N; however this does not seem to work; any idea on that as well?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid.  I've never used `mysqlreport`.  You can certainly get all the raw values by using `show status like 'Com%';` in any MySQL client.

Comment: Thanks for the help, certainly appreciate your quick and accurate answer(s).